# Java int... array notation

Tags: java, arrays

I've seen this before in a method parameter, and it appears to allow an arbitrary number of parameters to be stuffed in an array created at run-time. What's the official name of this language feature? Thanks!

```
    public static void trace(View view, RecyclerTraceType type, int... parameters) {

    RecyclerTrace trace = new RecyclerTrace();
    trace.position = parameters[0];
    trace.indexOnScreen = parameters[1];
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are seeing the Java 1.5 [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) feature. Under the hoods its just an array with syntactic sugaring.

Answer (score 3):

[Variadic Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.23.2C_VB.net.2C_and_Java)